# React: Moving component to different div on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React so any advice would be appreciated on how to move an agent thumbnail to the teamComp div when it is clicked.

I'm also lost as to how to tackle filtering the data through a dropdown menu. Like how would I update the page without refreshing so that only the agents with the selected roles appear.

Anything would help, like I said before, I am a complete beginner to React and feel like I am underutilizing a lot of what makes React powerful.

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import AgentCard from "./components/agentCard";
import Select from "react-select"

function App() {
  const options = useMemo(
    () => [
      {value: "controller", label: "Controller"},
      {value: "duelist", label: "Duelist"},
      {value: "initiator", label: "Initiator"},
      {value: "sentinel", label: "Sentinel"},
      
    ],
    []
  );

  const [agentDetails, setAgentDetails] = useState([]);

  const getAllAgents = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents/");
    const results = await res.json();

    const agentNames = [],
      agentImages = [],
      agentRoles = [],
      agentDetails = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(results["data"]).length; i++) {
      if (results["data"][i]["developerName"] != "Hunter_NPE") {
        agentNames.push(results["data"][i]["displayName"]);
        agentImages.push(results["data"][i]["displayIcon"]);
        agentRoles.push(results["data"][i]["role"]["displayName"]);
      } 
      else {
        continue;
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < agentNames.length; i++) {
      agentDetails[i] = [agentNames[i], [agentImages[i], agentRoles[i]]];
    }
    agentDetails.sort();
    setAgentDetails(agentDetails);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllAgents();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <h2>Valorant Team Builder</h2>
      <div className="teamComp">
      </div>
      <Select options={options} defaultValue={options} isMulti/>
      <div id="agent_container" className="agent-container">
        {agentDetails.map((agentDetails) => (
          <AgentCard
            img={agentDetails[1][0]}
            name={agentDetails[0]}
            role={agentDetails[1][1]}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

agentCard.js

```
import React from 'react'

const agentCard = ({role, name, img}) => {
    return (
        <div className="card-container">
            <div className="img-container">
                <img src={img} alt={name} />
            </div>
            <div className="info">
                <h3 className="name">{name}</h3>
                <small className="role"><span>Role: {role}</span></small>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default agentCard
```

index.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #EFEFBB;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #D4D3DD, #EFEFBB);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #D4D3DD, #EFEFBB);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.agent-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: space-between;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.app-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 3rem 0.5rem;
  }

.card-container {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-container:hover {
    filter: brightness(70%);
    transition: all 150ms ease;
}

.img-container img {
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}

.name {
    margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

.teamComp h3 {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Moving cards

To move a card to a different list you need a new state array that will represent "the members of the team". Something like:

```
const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);
```

Render the items in `team` inside the "teamComp" `<div>`, the same way you do it in the agent container.

Then add the new function prop to the card and use it in the `onClick` handler in the card `<div>`:

```
<AgentCard
  key={agentDetails[0]}
  img={agentDetails[1][0]}
  name={agentDetails[0]}
  role={agentDetails[1][1]}
  handleClick={moveToTeam}
/>

...

<div className="card-container" onClick={() => handleClick(name)}>
```

and in this function, add the `agentDetails` item to the `team` state and remove it from the `agentDetails` state. Make sure that you supply new arrays when setting state:

```
const moveToTeam = (name) => {
    const newTeam = [...team, agentDetails.find((agent) => agent[0] === name)];
    const newAgentDetails = agentDetails.filter((agent) => agent[0] !== name);
    setTeam(newTeam);
    setAgentDetails(newAgentDetails);
  };
```

### Filtering

For filtering you need another state that contains all selected options:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState(allOptions);
```

where `allOptions` is an array of all available options, and it should not change.

Add the `onChange` handler to the `<Select>` component:

```
<Select
  options={allOptions}
  onChange={(selectedOptions) => setOptions(selectedOptions)}
  defaultValue={allOptions}
  isMulti
/>
```

and finally use `options` to filter cards:

```
<div id="agent_container" className="agent-container">
  {agentDetails
    .filter(
      (agentDetails) =>
        options.filter((option) => option.label === agentDetails[1][1])
          .length > 0
    )
    .map((agentDetails) => (
      <AgentCard
        key={agentDetails[0]}
        img={agentDetails[1][0]}
        name={agentDetails[0]}
        role={agentDetails[1][1]}
        handleClick={moveToTeam}
      />
    ))}
</div>
```

You can see the complete example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/team-builder-zvx2b).

I left most of the names in place, although I think using `agentDetails` for different things is confusing. The data structures can also be improved, but I left them unchanged as well.